# SCSS: substitute scoped @import with @use

Tags: vue.js, sass

The official said that `@import` will be removed in years and recommend using `@use` instead.

I'm using scss with Vue, I can `@import` rules under `:v-deep`:

```
  .article__content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    ::v-deep() {
      @import 'highlight.js/scss/github';
    }
    .article {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

But how can I change it to `@use`? `@use` can only been used at beginning of file, and the file I'm importing is a pure stylesheet which doesn't include any mixins and variables.